# On Php Side result Getting Success But Notification not Receiving on android device

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working on push notification using firebase through php.
When I send notification from console it`s working properly.
When I sending it through php I am getting success result but android doesn't receving it.

My php rsponse:

```
"multicast_id": 64545454555454545498,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
    "message_id": "0:1555445451572%sfsdfdfdfd"
  }
]
```

I have tried to make a log inside `onrecevied()` method. Still I am not getting any log or response in android side.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Check your internet connectivity

Comment: net working properly

Comment: Can you show your android code?

Comment: Yes show your code